# Probability to belong in a class in a Proportional Odds Logistic Regression

Tags: ordered-logit, polr

I'm having trouble understanding how the probability of belonging to each class is being calculated. Appreciate it if someone could help me out!

Assuming the dependent variable with 3 ordinal classes (low, medium, high).

And assume for simplicity, the coefficients for a model with 2 predictors:

- b1 : 2
- b2 : -3

And intercept for low|medium:

- b0 : 1.5

And intercept for medium|high:

- a0 : 0.5

How do we find the probability that a new set of observations x0 = (x1 , x2) = (1,2) belongs to which class? Can you show how, using the equation for `polr`?

Thanks in advance for your help!